# Prompt option is invalid because process is not interactive

Tags: c#, windows, azure, iis, vs-web-site-project

We have Automated ADO ticket creation form in c# which allow users to input ticket title body when click of Submit button if we use admin account PAT token it creates ticket automatically.

In order to make user who creates ticket as submitter which helps them to follow ticket updates we are trying to submit ticket with interactive credentials.

using below code to connect to ADO.

```
Uri _uri = new Uri(collectionUri);
var creds = new VssClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(false),
                                     new VssFederatedCredential(),
                                     CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded);
creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

VssConnection vssConnection = new VssConnection(_uri, creds);
await vssConnection.ConnectAsync();
```

Local debugging just works fine and creates a ticket but when we host this to IIS it reports below error.

[image]

Any suggestions what settings do we need to enable to make the process interactive.

It is a website which is interactive and takes user input for ticket title body and other inputs.

Comment: It would be completely useless if there would be a prompt on the machine where IIS runs (i.e. the Web Server).

Comment: Make sure your application is deployed correctly.

Comment: We are publishing changes automatically to host, so there is no issue with deployment.

Comment: @KlausGütter Now build account is creating the userstory in Azure devops, requirement is ticket should be created by particular user who raises it, how to achieve this.